# Compare two regexs [ab]* and ([ab])\1

Tags: python, regex

What makes me wonder is that

- why `[ab]*` doesn't  repeat the matched part, but repeat `[ab]`. In other words, why it is not the same as either `a*`, or `b*`?
- why `([ab])\1` repeat the matched part, but not repeat `[ab]`. In other words, why it can only match `aa` and `bb`, but not `ab` and `ba`?

Is it because the priority  of  `()` is lower than `[]`, while the priority of `*` is higher than `[]`? I wonder ift thinking of these as operators might not be appropriate. Thanks.

Comment: `[ab]` means `a` or `b` and `\1` is a backreference which matches the same text matched by the 1st capturing group `( )`, therefore it will not match `ab` or `ba`

Comment: @hwnd:it is a typo. should be `([ab])\1`. I understand the meaning. but here I try to compar the differnt behaviours of the two regexs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They both are entirely different.

When you say `[ab]*`, it means that either `a` or `b` for zero or more times. So, it will match "", "a", "b", and any combination of `a` and `b`.

But `([ab])\1` means that either `a` or `b` will be matched and then it is captured. `\1` is called a backreference. It refers to the already captured group in the RegEx. In our case, `([ab])`. So, if `a` was captured, then it will match only `a` again. If it is `b` then it will match only `b` again. It can match only `aa` and `bb`.

Comment: I understood what you said. Thanks. I make my post a little clearer to clarify my questions better.

Answer (score 1):

```
[ab]*
```

This will also match nothing, `a`, `b`, `aaa`, `bbb`, and any length of a string. The match isn't constrained by length and since there are no capturing groups, its stating to match a string of any length consisting of all `a` and `b` characters.

```
([ab])\1
```

In which case it forces the matched string to be two characters since there is no repetition. First, it must match what's inside the parens (for capturing group one), then it must match what it captured in group 1, which implicitly forces the match to be two characters long with both characters being identical.

Comment: I understood what you said. Thanks. I make my post a little clearer to clarify my questions better.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at each of your expressions, then we'll add **one interesting twist** that may resolve any outstanding confusion.

`[ab]*` is equivalent to `(?:a|b)*`, in other words match `a` or `b` any number of times, for instance `abbbaab`.

`[ab]` is equivalent to `(?:a|b)`, in other words match `a` or `b` once, for instance `a`.

`a*` means match `a` any number of times (for instance, `aaaa`

`b*` means match `b` any number of times (for instance, `bb`

You say that `([ab])\1` can only match `aa` or `bb`. That is correct, because

`([ab])\1` means match `a` or `b` once, capturing it to Group 1, then match Group 1 again, i.e. `a` if we had `a`, or `b` if we had `b`.

**One more variation (Perl, PCRE)**

`([ab])(?1)` means match `a` or `b` once, capturing it to Group 1, then match the expression specified inside Group 1, therefore, match `[ab]` again. This would match `aa`, `ab`, `ba` or `bb`. Therefore,

`([ab])(?1)*` can match the same as `[ab]+`, and `([ab]*)(?1)*` can match the same as `[ab]*`

Comment: thanks. Can `.*` match `ab`? If not, why can `[ab]*` can match `ab`?

Comment: @Tim Yes, it can (since dot means "any character")

Comment: You said that `([ab])\1` match `a` or `b` once. Does `[ab]*` match `a` or `b` arbitrary times?

Comment: @Tim `You said that ([ab])\1 match a or b once` Not quite, I said that (`[ab]`) matches a or b once, then that `\1` matches once again what was just matched and captured. `Does [ab]* match a or b arbitrary times?` Yes, you got that right. Please understand that `[abc]` is a character class that means "match any of the characters inside the brackets exactly once". The `*` is a quantifier that means "match what the expression to the left of me is trying to match, zero or more times"

Comment: In `([ab])\1`, `\1` means to match **what is matched** i.e. group 1. In `[ab]*`, `*` is to match **the original query** `[ab]`. Is that why the former doesn't match `ab`, while the latter can match `ab`?

Comment: @Tim Sorry for the delay, didn't see your message. `Is that why the former doesn't match ab, while the latter can match ab` Yes, you got it. The `\1` refers to the `a` or `b` that was just matched, so `([ab])\1` can only match the same thing twice: `aa` or `bb`. In contrast, in `[ab]*` the `*` means repeat zero or more times: "match an a OR a b", so we can have bab, baba, aaa etc. Feel free to invite me to chat if you have more questions (I'm not sure how that works). :)